# Link Server's alternate

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to write some sp's which will retrieved rows from two different server. I do not want to use Link server or open query. Is there any other way? My plan is to create two different sp in different server and then access both in data in front end and from front end i will write the logic. I think it will be complicated.

We are now migrating some part of one vb 6 application to .net. The database for vb 6 is sql 2000 and it will be in one server. In .net the database will be in sql 2008. Now we have created some tables in sql server 2008 which were avilable in sql 2000. We need to call same sp's of the vb application from .net. now because of some table has been changed from sql server 2000 to 2008 i am getting problem. Please suggest. Let me know if you clearly understood the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, you have two choices here, assuming you want to make these calls from a stored procedure:

1. Use Linked Servers (which you don't want to do)
2. Write your stored procedures as CLR procedures and create your own database connections in your C# (or VB.NET) CLR code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have an idea that CLR procedure are not usefull in real development. Is this right? Can you please tell how to write this in clr procedure. Can i create two connection in clr(I have No idea on Clr sp's) and do all the manipulation like insert update delete and temp table, looping. and how complicated it will be.

Comment: @User593820 - I cannot possibly explain how to write a CLR procedure via StackOverflow. But there is plenty of documentation around on how to do it. I believe you can create as many connections as you need in a CLR procedure.